# Crimped lugs or screw terminal for high current (100Amp-200Amp) connection

Tags: crimp, terminal-block

I am tidying the wiring in a motorhome that has got a bit out of hand over the years,
the motorhome runs two 12V house batteries connected in parallel, I want to tidy the birds nest and improve circuit protection of the wiring that goes directly to the batteries.

What I plan to do as add a busbar for the negative connection, and add a fused distribution box to replace numerous inline fuses. With the connections, particularly the high power ones, what is the preferred termination method. Should I use crimp lugs and M6 or M8 bolts/screws on the busbar/fuse box (I have access to hydraulic crimper), or is it better to use fuse box/busbar that is a  terminal block with ferrules on the cable ends?

Connections into the battery include a 1000W inverter (Call it 100Amp), 50Amp total of solar generation and the factory supply which is fused at 50AMp, along with a couple of small (<1Amp) sized devices directly connected to battery.

I am pragmatic about voltage drop, the factory wiring is probably on the small side so another couple of points of a volt won't matter.  The invert is 6" from the batteries with maybe a foot of 0AWG. The main bigger currents of  100Amp and 50Amp obviously voltage drop at the terminal become an issue with heat before it becomes an issue with some nominal 'too much'.

Comment: Depends on your power and tolerance for voltage drop

Comment: @Tony - see edit.

Comment: Crimp lugs are the common method.

Comment: anything with  Rja * Rs  * I^2 > 50'C rise is a concern